# Why isn't there a "search" option on the site?

Tags: discussion

We expect people to do some research before asking a question, especially with duplicate questions.  But I note that there is no site search option.

Wouldn't that be helpful for people, ultimately reducing questions ending up in the review queue?

UPDATE - here is a screenshot, no search box

[image]

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "site search", and how is it different from the search box at the top of every page?

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister see my screenshot.  Should there be a search box?  Firefox with Privacy Badger and Ad Block Plus  and Duck Duck Go, but disabling them didn't make a difference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either your screenshot cut off the black bar at the top, or one of your extensions is removing it. I also use Firefox as my primary browser, and it works fine for me.

[image: Webmasters site search]

I have a search shortcut installed in Firefox for Webmasters site search. I have `https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=%s` bookmarked with the `Keyword` set to `w`. Then I can just type "w keywords" into the URL bar and it will search on webmasters with the words I'm searching for replacing the `%s` in the bookmark.

[image: webmasters site search keyword bookmark]

Comment: hahaha....well now I feel stupid - I have dark mode enabled on my browser so the black bar kind of blended into the toolbars.    I can't believe it...I have been a webmastersSE member for over 10 years and still missed it.

Comment: Sometimes we all need a red circle. :)